# Deploying Rails 4 to VPS with cpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, cpanel, vps

**My steps**

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 4 application to subdomain on VPS with cpanel installed.

I added a subdomain msystem.mydomain.com in cpanel GUI. Root directory set to "/home/web/public_html/msystem".

Next I install RVM, ruby 2.1.2, rails 4 and passenger.

Then added

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
```

to pre_main_2.conf in cpanel GUI (there is installed only apache 2.2.26).

Then I made all the RVM files world-readable

```
chmod ugo+rX -R /usr/local/rvm
```

In the `/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/web/msystem.mydomain.com/msystem.conf` I added line

```
DocumentRoot /home/web/public_html/msystem/public/
```

Then `bundle install --deployment`, `rake db:migrate`.

I used [Dave James Miller](https://davejamesmiller.com/blog/installing-rails-3-1-ruby-1-9-on-a-cpanel-11-30-server) and [blog.barrioearth.com](http://blog.barrioearth.com/cpanel-ruby-on-rails-phusion-passenger/) tutorials.

**Problem**

msystem.mydomain.com/ is redirecting to msystem.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

---

**UPDATE**

Apache redirects only '/' request. With other routes it works right way. There is a root route in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root 'categories#index'
```

My virtual host in httpd.conf looks like:
http://pastebin.com/hRgSRD6A

Comment: Did you find the remarks regarding Passenger 4 being better than 3 for RVM at http://rvm.io/deployment/passenger and setting `PassengerRuby` to be helpful for multiple apps?

Comment: I didn't compare them. I have changed my hosting not to use cpanel. Now I'm using nginx+Unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was DNS or browser cache issue. On other computers '/' route works well.